# How to show not closed under addition/closed under addition? (Specific exam question)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need help in part (i) and the part where I am to show that $V_3$ is a linear space.

[image: Linear space and closure under addition]

I understand that I am required to show that, in part (i), $V_1$ ∪ $V_2$ is not closed under addition; I would love to ask for a complete guide on how to show it, albeit not required by the question.

Also, I am also required to show that $V_3$ is a linear space. It is not hard to show that it has the zero vector, but can someone guide me on how to show, step by step, that it is closed under addition and multiplication?

I've looked for guides on how to show closed under addition/multiplication but I am not able to apply it in this kind of question.

Comment: To show closure under addition just let $v$ and $w$ be in $V_3$ and show that $v + w \in V_3$. Then do the same thing for multiplication but show $vw \in V_3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (i), consider
$$
v_{1}=(0,0,1,0)=b_{3}-b_{2}\in V_{1}
$$
and
$$
v_{2}=(0,0,1,1)=b_{4}-b_{2}\in V_{2}.
$$
Then, set 
$$
v=v_{1}+v_{2}=(0,0,2,1).
$$
Note that $v\notin V_{1}$ since it has a nonzero entry in the 4th coordinate. Also, $v\notin V_{2}$ since every vector in $V_{2}$ has identical 3rd and 4th coordinates.

To see that $V_{3}$ is a linear space, let $u_{i}=q_{i}b_{2}+r_{i}b_{3}+s_{i}b_{4}$ for $i=1,2$. Then, $u_{1}+u_{2}=(q_{1}+q_{2})b_{2}+(r_{1}+r_{2})b_{3}+(s_{1}+s_{2})b_{4}\in V_{3}$. Also, if $k$ is a scalar, $ku_{1}=kq_{1}b_{2}+kr_{1}b_{3}+ksb_{4}\in V_{3}$. Hence, $V_{3}$ is a linear space.